# Device firmware update over BLE from STM32 to NRF device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52, dfu

Is it possible to update the firmware from an STM32 device to NRF device over [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy)?

What is a step-by-step approach to achieve this? The update procedure includes: Prepare the firmware update, transfer the firmware, verify and execute the updated firmware.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to update a NRF device by sending the firmware from an STM32 or the other way arround?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Technically you can do a firmware upgrade of the nRF52 using any BLE device, given that at the end of the day you're just transferring hex packets over BLE. That being said, it is not a trivial task and will probably take weeks (if not months) to implement. Nordic provide libraries for Android and iOS for doing [OTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_update) upgrades which might speed up the process, but these libraries don't exist for other platforms (i.e., STM32).

Have a look at the links below as they have references on how to achieve this:

- [Nordic bootloader and DFU modes](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v15.0.0%2Flib_bootloader_modules.html&cp=9_5_4_3_5)
- [Implementing OTA device firmware update for nRF52](https://novelbits.io/ota-device-firmware-update-part-2/)
- [Nordic DFU like a rockstar](https://dojofive.com/blog/nordic-dfu-like-a-rockstar/)
- [iOS DFU libraries](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-DFU-Library)
- [Android DFU libraries](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library)